# patterns `&Unspecified` and `&__Nonexhaustive` not covered

Tags: rust

I'm getting this on a `match` block:

```
patterns `&Unspecified` and `&__Nonexhaustive` not covered
```

The code:

```
fn vipaddress_from_ipddress(address: &IpAddress) -> VIpAddress {
    match address {
```

I think `&Unspecified` has something to do with not accounting for null case, but references in Rust cannot be null. What is  `&__Nonexhaustive`?

Comment: It's defined in your `enum` somewhere. You can always have a `_ => ()` "don't care" pattern, though unless your return type accepts that you'll need to deal with it somehow. Rust is saying "What do you want to do for those potential cases?"

Comment: What is `IpAddress` and how is the full `match` statement constructed?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `IpAddress` is from [smoltcp](https://docs.rs/smoltcp/0.6.0/smoltcp/wire/enum.IpAddress.html), and the match only matches the `Ipv4` and `Ipv6` variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an undocumented enum variant: https://docs.rs/ethox/0.0.1-wip/src/ethox/wire/ip.rs.html#15

This possibly indicates that the developer does not expect the users of `IpAddress` to `match`; maybe there is already a function doing what you want?

Comment: Which is usually used *specifically* to avoid exhaustive matching. In fact, Rust 1.40 added [`non_exhaustive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html#the-non_exhaustive-attribute) specifically for that usecase.

Comment: @Masklinn Isn't there a specific attribute `non_exhaustive` for exactly the same purpose?

Comment: it was added in 1.40 or so, so not an option for packages trying to support older rustc versions, also possible dev' is not aware.